# sleep mode not working when is plugged in

Tags: release-freya, power

I've set the configs to go to sleep after 30  minutes of inactivity when the laptop is plugged in but there's just a notify that indicates the laptop will go to sleep because of inactivity soon but it never goes to sleep.

Anybody has a similar problem? or some idea of what could it be?

Elementary Freya on Toshiba satellite c655.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? It looks like a bug but I don't see anything along these lines in the tracker

Comment: @wolf I don't have the same computer anymore.

Comment: I am having same issue here. I am using Lenovo Ideapad. My laptop does not suspend even though I have setting in power management